# Perform strftime on created_at in pluck

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In Rails, how can I perform a .strftime on created_at in a .pluck?

I'm simply trying to convert the created_at inline:

```
Entry.where(client_id: @client).pluck(:created_at, :amount)
```

created_at is spitting out wrong for my Chartkick scatter chart, and I'd like to do a simple conversion, such as

```
@client.created_at.strftime("%m")
```

My understanding of Pluck is that, unlike Select, a model method override is not available.

Is it possible to .map it inline while still doing the strftime conversion and outputting as an array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pluck [returns an Array](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck) of attribute values therefore you can map pluck result:

```
Entry
  .where(client_id: @client)
  .pluck(:created_at, :amount)
  .map { |e| [ e[0].strftime("%m"), e[1] ] }
```